# Angular Material mat-form-field appearance="outline"

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material, material-design, mat-form-field

i use Material 16. I would like mat-form-field with appearance="outline" but the label should inside my InputField. CURRENTLY it looks like this

[image]

But i want this.

[image]

If i use <mat-form-field appearance="fill" (2nd picture) my border is away. i would like use the border too.